# sliderInput resets if other inputs change

Tags: r, animation, shiny

When you change the '`speed control`' the '`timeRange`' `sliderInput` resets to the minimum value. I would like it to start it at the 'current' value of the slider. The main slider is the `timeRange` slider. Also, I would like to disable the `speed` and `step_size` sliders when the animation is playing and make them usable only when the animation is paused.

Any suggestions please?

Here is my code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("tester"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(id="sidebar",
                 uiOutput("slider"),
                 uiOutput("speed_value"), 
                 uiOutput("step_size")
    ),
    mainPanel(
              h4(textOutput("selectedtime"))
              )
    )
  )

server <- function(input, output) {
  minimum.slider <- "2016-08-12 UTC"
  maximum.slider <- "2016-08-30 05:29:00 UTC"
  output$slider <- renderUI({

    ## MAIN slider input into the output. The step depends on user defined 'speed' and 'interval depends on user defined 'step size'
    sliderInput("timeRange", label = "Date/Time:", width = '600px',
                min = minimum.slider,
                max = maximum.slider,
                value = minimum.slider,
                step = (60*input$step_size),
                timezone = "UTC",
                animate = animationOptions(interval = 3200 - (input$speed*300),
                                           playButton = tags$img(height = 40,width = 45,
                                                                 src = "https://png.icons8.com/color/1600/circled-play", 
                                                                 tags$p(tags$b("PLAY"))),
                                           pauseButton = tags$img(height = 40, width = 45,
                                                                  src = "https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/perfect-flat-icons-2/512/Pause_button_play_stop_blue.png",
                                                                  tags$p(tags$b("PAUSE"))))
    )

  })

  ##animation speed control
  output$speed_value <- renderUI({
    sliderInput("speed",
                label = div(style='width:300px;',
                            div(style='float:left;', 'slower'),
                            div(style='float:right;', 'faster')),
                min = 1, 
                max = 10, 
                value = 6, 
                width = '300px')

  })

  ##time step definition by user
  output$step_size <- renderUI({
    sliderInput("step_size","Time Steps (minutes):",
                min = 10, max = 60, value = 1, width = '300px')
  })

  ##OUTPUT
  observe({
    output$selectedtime <- renderText({
      paste(format(input$timeRange))
    })

  })
}
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Use `updateSliderInput` instead

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. Yes, I have tried updateSliderInput in the 'observe' part of the server but it didn't help..

Comment: also replace with `isolate(input$step_size)...` each input in `sliderInput("timeRange"...)`

Comment: Tried adding this to the 'observe'. It ended up with an error. of unused arguments. updateSliderInput(session,"timeRange", label = "Date/Time:", width = '600px',
                    min = minimum.slider,
                    max = maximum.slider,
                    value = isolate(input$timeRange),
                    step = (60*isolate(input$step_size)),
                    timezone = "UTC",
                    animate = animationOptions(interval = 3200 - (isolate(input$speed)*300))

Comment: Add the isolate at `sliderInput`not `updateSliderInput`...

Comment: Yes I tried the other way round too. it changes my date format which is not compatible with the minimum and maximum values of the slider.

Comment: Thanks HubertL. I have finally cured this issue with your help. Both updatesliderinput and isolate seem to work now. I was putting them under wrong hoods! Now I have another issue though. I have posted it if you would like to help :) Thanks again.